# Calling second method from first method changes behaviour of first method

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email to two different mail servers. I have a method that points to one mail server `send` and another method that points to a different mail server `sendSecond`. I want the email to go to both email servers, but by calling the second mail server method in the first it sends the email twice to the second mail server and nothing to the first mail server. Why? And how do I get it to send to both email servers?

First mail server: `Settings.instance().getMailServerIp()`

Second mail server: `Settings.instance().getSecondMailServerIp()`

```
    public synchronized void send(DefaultEmail defaultEmail, Set<User> to) {
    System.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", Settings.instance().getMailServerIp());
    Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
    executor.execute(new FutureTask<Void>(new EmailTask(defaultEmail, to)));
    sendSecond(defaultEmail, to);
}

public synchronized void sendSecond(DefaultEmail defaultEmail, Set<User> to) {
    System.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", Settings.instance().getSecondMailServerIp());
    Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
    executor.execute(new FutureTask<Void>(new EmailTask(defaultEmail, to)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mail.smtp.host` property works kind of like a global variable. There is only one such setting. When you call `send`, you create a `FutureTask` that delivers the mail later. Then you call `sendSecond`, which changes the `mail.smtp.host` to the second mail server, and schedules a second task to deliver the mail.

Sometime later, both those future tasks run and deliver the mail to the current value of `mail.smtp.host` (which now points to the second mail server).

You will probably want to find a way to deliver the mail to a *specific* mail server instead of relying on the global `mail.smtp.host` property.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. How could I get the email sent to  both email servers?

Comment: @Jason: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the specific libraries you're using to send email to give a complete answer to that. A quick search of the javamail API docs indicates that you will want to create two `Session` objects, where each contains specific settings for each server.